# pandas dictionary formation exiting code before completion of iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a dictionary of a data frame with 18330 rows.
but the dictionary is stopping at 15275th row.
I am not able to understand the root cause for the same.

'''

```
final_dict = dict()
item = df1['Item Code']
id = df1['store ID']
sp = df1['Selling Price']
mrp = df1['MRP']

for a in range(0, item.__len__()):
    key = str(item[a]) + "|" + str(id[a])
    value = str(sp[a]) + "|" + str(mrp[a])
    final_dict[key] = value
    key_list = final_dict.keys()


print(item.__len__())
print(len(final_dict))
print(len(key_list))
print(len(df1.index))
df1['key'] = key_list
print(df1)
```

'''

```
Output: 
18330
15275
15275
18330
error : "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"
```

Dataframe Sample:

[image]

Can anyone help me understand my mistake here.

Comment: Can you add in the post a dataframe that can be used for reproducing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible that the ItemCode and StoreID combination is getting repeated in your data. And since the key already exists in dictionary only the value is getting updated. Check you file for repetitions.

Comment: Yes, there were duplicates. I cant beleive it could be such a small thing.. Thanks you.